# Renaming File Names Using Python

Tags: python, regex, rename

Sorry if this question is too basic, I've been searching python and regex and haven't found exactly what I need.

I have a bunch of television show files with names that end in S01EXX like the following:

```
filename.S01E01.mkv
filename.S01E02.mkv
filename.S01E03.mkv
```

Each of this is actually a double episode, so the above three should be named with the form:

```
filename.S01E01-E02.mkv
filename.S01E03-E04.mkv
filename.S01E05-E06.mkv
```

so each should be the episode number times 2 minus 1, and the episode number times 2. I know how to rename and split with python, I just don't know how to go about parsing out the episode numbers and how deal with the leading zero that will disappear when we get to 2 digit episode numbers.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the position of the episode number is constant, you can extract it using a slice:

```
e = int(filename[-6:-4])
new_filename = '%s%02d-E%02d%s' % (filename[:-6], e*2-1, e*2, filename[-4:])
```

Comment: Filename slicing, combined with regex pattern matching, saved me a couple hours of labor today. Good combo!